# How to programatically allow a Windows 8 app to run background tasks?

Tags: windows-8, powershell, automation, modern-ui

When you run a Windows 8 modern UI (previously called Metro) app that has background tasks, you must explicitly choose if it is allowed to run background tasks.

[image: Windows Background Task]

Is there a way to automate this?

I have tried watching the registry with ProcMon and dumped registry changes before and after allowing the app to run in background but exporting and importing the differences did not work.

I also tried copying the c:\Users\\Settings\settings.dat file and it also didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I know this is probably a dumb question, but have you tried task scheduler?

Comment: Modern UI applications cannot run in the background.  If they do not have focus they are placed into a suspended mode.  Only a few key features are able to work in this mode.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm talking about these background tasks: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/24/being-productive-in-the-background-background-tasks.aspx

Comment: @Ramhound: From that link seems any Metro app can be coded to run in the background.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean can you take a Metro UI application that was not designed to run with a background  task component and get it to run in the background?  If so, the answer is no.  The developer must specify at design time when the application is created that the app will have a background task and add that background task as part of the application creation.

Or do you mean is there a way to programmatically get around the dialog box asking a user's permission to run a background task.  If so, the answer is, again, no.  This is part of the security design of the Windows Store Application environment.  Security is much, much tighter than previous editions of Windows and many things you could do before are no longer allowed.  This is by design.

Comment: I meant the latter :) Microsoft does not allow you to launch Windows Store apps via the command line too, but you can do it with PowerShell scripts. Considering this is for testing purposes, I believe there must be a way to do this, even if it is not officially supported by Microsoft.